# How to detect server response changed and reload data without using Pull-To-Refresh in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, pull-to-refresh

How can I check the server response has changed and populate it without using `Pull-To-Refresh`. I have previously implemented that and know how to use it and it works fine.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshBrandList:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

-(void) refreshBrandList:(id)sender{
    [self ServiceCall];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];


}
```

But I want to detect automatically the server response has changed and want to perform the work of `Pull-To-Refresh` without using it.

Comment: make a custom statement called checkForUpdates that is on a  timer that checks every 5 seconds or whatever you want and have it check your source. Then use if/else statement like `if(something new found){ [self.tableview reloadData];}`

Comment: NSTimer make application slow so is there any other options

Comment: It shouldn't, it's a background task. How important is it to you that you need updates? How often is something new going to be changed or added? A lot of frameworks automatically update for you like Parse or Meteor.

Comment: What does fb use to update its task automatically

Comment: Facebook uses push notifications. Facebook I believe, but could be wrong, is a web interfaced app, not a traditional mobile phone app made in Xcode. So everything is done online instead of through the device.

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 5.0 target: self
                                   selector: @selector(callAfterFiveSecond:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

-(void) callAfterFiveSecond:(NSTimer*) t
{
 [self ServiceCall];
 [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

You can use it Using NSTimer.

**Another option is using silent Push Notification.

Comment: NSTimer make application slow so is there any other options

Comment: Another option is using silent Push Notification.

Comment: Isnt that heavy task for just reloading smthng